# What Hibernate 3.5.1 Dialect is best for accessing MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Right now I am using InnoDB tables but what confuses me is what if I am using more than one engine in the DB?

Since I used 'best' in the title it warns that the question is subjective but considering the very finite numbers of Dialects in question and that I don't understand the discriminating factors between them (what best *is*) I need this explained in the answer.

For reference here are the Dialects in question found under org.hibernate.dialect:

- MySQL5Dialect
- MySQL5InnoDBDialect
- MySQLDialect
- MySQLInnoDBDialect
- MySQLMyISAMDialect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL InnoDB enforces referential integrity; ISAM does not.

MySQL version 5 is distinct from earlier versions.

MySQLDialect is probably legacy from the first Hibernate implementation, when there was no such choice.

Choose the one that best matches your version of MySQL (version 5 from your question) and the implementation you've used to create to your MySQL database.

Comment: Alright seems very straight forward, I was prompted to ask after a jpa2 criteria query is throwing "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query" if I'm using MySQL5Dialect, MySQLDialect or MySQL5InnoDBDialect... It will be the subject of another question.

Comment: Are you should you asked for InnoDB when you created the MySQL tables?

Comment: Yes it was a silly issue of naming a column a reserved word "group".  I found that the issue could be fixed if I either renamed the column name annotation from "group" to "`group`" but I worried that might cause an issue so I just renamed the column and regenerated the entity.